# Add multiple columns lagged by one year

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, time-series, regression

I need to add a 1-year-lagged version of multiple columns from my dataframe. Here's my data:

```
data<-data.frame(Year=c("2011","2011","2011","2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013"), 
                 Country=c("America","China","India","America","China","India","America","China","India"),
                 Value1=c(234,443,754,334,117,112,987,903,476),
                 Value2=c(2,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,2))
```

And I want to add two columns that contain Value1 and Value2 at t-1, so that my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

How can I do this? Would this be the correct way to lag my variables by year?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Using *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
cols <- grep("^Value", colnames(data), value = TRUE)
data[, paste0(cols, "_lag") := lapply(.SD, shift), .SDcols = cols, by = Country]
#    Year Country Value1 Value2 Value1_lag Value2_lag
# 1: 2011 America    234      2         NA         NA
# 2: 2011   China    443      4         NA         NA
# 3: 2011   India    754      5         NA         NA
# 4: 2012 America    334      6        234          2
# 5: 2012   China    117      7        443          4
# 6: 2012   India    112      8        754          5
# 7: 2013 America    987      1        334          6
# 8: 2013   China    903      2        117          7
# 9: 2013   India    476      2        112          8
```

Answer (score 2):

In `dplyr`, use `lag` by group:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0
data %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("Value"), lag, .names = "{col}_lagged"), .by = Country)

  Year Country Value1 Value2 Value1_lagged Value2_lagged
1 2011 America    234      2            NA            NA
2 2011   China    443      4            NA            NA
3 2011   India    754      5            NA            NA
4 2012 America    334      6           234             2
5 2012   China    117      7           443             4
6 2012   India    112      8           754             5
7 2013 America    987      1           334             6
8 2013   China    903      2           117             7
9 2013   India    476      2           112             8
```

Below 1.1.0:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(across(c(GDP, Population), lag, .names = "{col}_lagged")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks! I do not want to substitute the columns though, just add the lagged version to the dataframe. Also, in my original dataframe, the columns to be lagged are called GDP and Population, is there a way to do this without using ```contains()```?

Comment: Sure, use `.names` as in the edit, and use `c(GDP, Population)` instead of using `contains`

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason if I use this code on my real data (which are identical to the dummy df provided in the question, but with more years and countries), I get another column that is identical to the one that is not lagged (except for the name) and a column named ```.by``` with the country names... Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, you have not updated to `dpyr 1.1.0`. You can use `group_by` otherwise. `.by` is a new feature to do inline grouping

Comment: Updated ```dplyr```, but when I try to use more than one column , I get this error: ```Error in `mutate()`:
In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error:
! All unnamed arguments must be length 1
Backtrace:
  1. df %>% ...
  3. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  4. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
  6. dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
  7. dplyr:::expand_across(dot)
  8. dplyr:::across_setup(...)
 10. glue::glue(names, .envir = glue_mask)
 11. glue::glue_data(...)
 12. base::stop("All unnamed arguments must be length 1", call. = FALSE)```

Comment: Check my edit with manually select columns

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `dplyr` to ge tthe job done.

```
library(dplyr)
data_lagged <- data %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Value1_Lagged = lag(Value1),
         Value2_Lagged = lag(Value2),
         Year = as.integer(as.character(Year)) + 1)
data_final <- cbind(data, data_lagged[, c("Value1_Lagged", "Value2_Lagged")])
data_final
```

Output:

```
  Year Country Value1 Value2 Value1_Lagged Value2_Lagged
1 2011 America    234      2            NA            NA
2 2011   China    443      4            NA            NA
3 2011   India    754      5            NA            NA
4 2012 America    334      6           234             2
5 2012   China    117      7           443             4
6 2012   India    112      8           754             5
7 2013 America    987      1           334             6
8 2013   China    903      2           117             7
9 2013   India    476      2           112             8
```